# ReactJS and Stormpath

Tags: reactjs, stormpath

I'm currently learning ReactJS and i'm following this tutorial :
https://stormpath.com/blog/build-a-react-app-with-user-authentication

I don't have a problem with it and everything is working fine. Howether, i'm trying to do some modifications, and the problem i have now is just displaying the current user name.

While reading the stormpath doc, i saw that i could do that :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { LoginLink, LogoutLink, Authenticated, NotAuthenticated } from 'react-stormpath';

class UserExample extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        user: React.PropTypes.object
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <p>
                Hello {this.context.user.givenName}!
            </p>
        );
    }
}
```

But it seems i have an error on "this.context.user.givenName", it says to me that context is not exported. I don't really find what to do or even what i am missing. Does someone got a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/bandini/my-react-app/src/pages/Header.js: Missing class properties transform.
class UserExample extends React.Component {
> static contextTypes = {
   ^
user: React.PropTypes.object
};

(With the ^, for indicating the error, just under "static")

Comment: Try to replace static property by `UserExample.contextTypes = { ... }` It seams your transpiler does not supports `static` class properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it didn't work. But i make it work by doing this :      `var UserName = React.createClass({
 contextTypes: {
  user: React.PropTypes.object
 },

 render: function() {
  return (
   <p>
    Hello {this.context.user.givenName}!
   </p>
  );
 }
});`   I don't really understand why it's not working by doing "export default class extends" etc or even what's the difference between React.createClass and extends React.Components.

Comment: First you should to define class component. Next, assign `contextTypes` and only after it you should use `export default UserExample`. Technically, there are no difference between `React.createClass` and components, defined with `class`. Class components are simply es6 syntax sugar.